# WSUSについて

Tags: windows

Windows Server 2016とWindows 10でWSUS構築の練習をしています。

Windows Serverに関する書籍はある程度読んできたのですが、WSUSについて明確に触れられているものに出会えていないため有識者の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授ください。

まずはじめにWSUSとは、サーバ側であらゆる更新プログラムを一挙に受け取り、サーバに登録したクライアントはプル形式でそのプログラムをインストールするという認識であっていますか。
サーバ側に登録していれば自動的にスケジュールに従って配られるようなイメージだったのですが、間違っていますか。

また、「Update Services」の画面なのですが、

1. 「更新プログラム」タブの「緊急更新プログラム」と「セキュリティ更新プログラム」アイコンの赤い矢印、「WSUSの更新プログラム」を開くと0件というのはどういった状態なのでしょうか。サーバ側でウィザードが開いて操作する工程がありましたが、そこで妙な設定をしてしまったためでしょうか。
2. 「同期」とは何でしょうか。これが完了すればひとまずサーバにあらゆるプログラムがすべてインストールされたということになりますか。
3. クライアント側がプル形式でサーバからプログラムを取得してくるとすれば、どういった操作が必要になりますか。

非常に取り留めのない質問の仕方になってしまっており申し訳ございません。ひとまず現状構築できている環境の詳細としましては、

「すべてのコンピューター」からクライアントを認識することはできていること、同期は進行中であること（約2時間経ってまだ80%未満ですが）、AD環境ではないということです。

どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) で挙げられている項目に該当しないような気がします。

Comment: StackExchange内で言えば[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)にするべき質問ではありますが、現在の所Server Fault日本語版がありません。そのため、「[サーバー管理・設置等の質問もここでいいです。](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292#311)」という意見もあります。ひとまず、上記理由で私は「オープンのままにする」に一票入れます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> まずはじめにWSUSとは、サーバ側であらゆる更新プログラムを一挙に受け取り、

更新プログラムを管理する対象製品はWSUSに設定できます。自組織で利用していないことが明らかな製品は除外した方がよいです。

> サーバに登録したクライアントはプル形式でそのプログラムをインストールするという認識であっていますか。

正確には、「そのWSUSサーバを参照するよう設定されたクライアント」です。サーバ側で登録するわけではありません。

> サーバ側に登録していれば自動的にスケジュールに従って配られるようなイメージだったのですが、間違っていますか。

- 前記の通り、クライアントをサーバに登録する訳ではありません。
- WSUSサーバは能動的に更新プログラムを配るわけではありません。

> 「更新プログラム」タブの「緊急更新プログラム」と「セキュリティ更新プログラム」アイコンの赤い矢印、「WSUSの更新プログラム」を開くと0件というのはどういった状態なのでしょうか。サーバ側でウィザードが開いて操作する工程がありましたが、そこで妙な設定をしてしまったためでしょうか。

赤矢印は特に意味が無かったような気がします。あまり気にしたことがないです。更新プログラムが表示されていないのは、以下が考えられます

- 初期同期中
- 該当のプログラムがダウンロードされるよう設定されていない(製品または更新プログラムのカテゴリ)
- フィルタで除外されている

> 「同期」とは何でしょうか。これが完了すればひとまずサーバにあらゆるプログラムがすべてインストールされたということになりますか。

アップストリームサーバとWSUSサーバの状態の同期です。

、更新プログラムの情報(有効無効・依存関係・その他諸々)の更新と、更新プログラムのダウンロード(インストールではなく)が行われます。

> クライアント側がプル形式でサーバからプログラムを取得してくるとすれば、どういった操作が必要になりますか。

通常のWindows Updateと同じです。手動または指定したスケジュールでWSUSサーバに問い合わせを行い必要なものをダウンロード・インストールします